# Synchronizing data from server and android device

Tags: android, synchronization

I implemented a web platform and an android app where users are having a profile and they can save some data, images, etc. and the system has to stay synchronized. Until now I simply used [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to notify the android device when the user added data on the web platform and simple `HTTP Requests` when the user added data on the android device. It worked fine.

Now the requirements changed. The android App should now also provide an offline mode. The user should be able to change the data on the android device while being offline. The data should be synchronized later when the device is online again. So now I can't work with `GCM` and simple `HTTP Requests` anymore because while the device is offline the user can change data on the device AND on the web platform. So I need a solution to synchronize the data.

My first suggestion was to use a database which is able to synchronize automatically like [Pouch DB](http://pouchdb.com/) for example. If there is no such database working for android i need some really complex merging mechanism. For static data like profile informations it is no problem. A simple timestamp would do the trick. But for dynamic data like lists of values it is more complex.

Does someone has experience with this kind of functionality especially the automatic synchronization of databases? Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLlite for that. 
Check if the app is now connected to the internet. If true, check if the user has change the data offline (you can use SharedPreferences where you can store a flag which is boolean). 
If flag is true, access the changed data in the SQllite and post to the server.
You can use a service to check in the background if device is offline or not.

How complicated is your database BTW?
Sorry i can't comment on your question at the moment.